# Encountering half pixels when scaling down to ldpi on Android?

Tags: android, image

I've got an image at 100x100px at xhdpi and to convert to ldpi its says it has to be 37.50px? do people round things off? Or re-do sizes with ldpi in mind?

Answer (score 1):

My personal advice is to ignore LDPI completely and let Android handle the scaling. It's a negligible segment of the market, and is not really worth worrying about.

That said, if you really want to do it, I'd round to the nearest even integer. 38px probably.